# Powershell / xaml - Combobox of Checkboxes get selected Items

Tags: powershell, xaml

I've implemented a ComboBox of CheckBoxes and it display well in the GUI. the thing is I can't find which item is checked. It always return null.
Here is my xaml:

```
<ComboBox  Name="ComboBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="161,141,0,0"           `VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="228"  FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" AutomationProperties.IsRequiredForForm="True">
   <ComboBox.Resources>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
              <Setter Property="Template">
                  <Setter.Value>
                     <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                         <CheckBox >
                              <ContentPresenter />
                          </CheckBox>
                     </ControlTemplate>
                  </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
         </Style>
     </ComboBox.Resources>
    <ComboBoxItem>item 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>item 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>item 3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>item 4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Option 4</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

And the code to get selected items.

```
$Button.Add_Click({
    Write-Host  "Items" + $ComboBox1.Text;
    $selectedItems = $ComboBox1.SelectedItems
    if ($selectedItems) {
        $selectedItems | ForEach-Object {
        $content = $_.Content`
        Write-Host "Selected Item: $content"
       }
     }
})
```

Am I missing something, or anything I should add?

Comment: This is a common thing in almost all programming languages, so not a PS-specific issue. However several SO Q&As cover the topic of what you are after. Just use the search box above to find them.  
  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=powershell+xaml+checkbox

Comment: I found a solution, thx you for your help.

Comment: No worries, and gald you found a resolution. In most cases, any legitimate IT/Programming question (except unique cases), has already been asked in some manner shape or form, on SO and all over the web.  Sure, you may not find your answer in one spot, but gather the pieces, steps thur them, and combine them as needed. It's just a matter of searching with the prudent question string or partial string in the search box provided above, even the use of logical operators in those search strings and explicit quoting will help.  Master ***'Google Dorking' ***  ;-} 
  ... Take care.